# How many integers whose total number of prime factors is prime are there below x?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let  $ \Omega(n) $  be the total number of prime factors of a positive integer  $ n $. Denote by  $\mathbb{P}_{\Omega}(x) $ the number of positive integers  $ n $ not exceeding  $ x $ such that  $ \Omega(n)\in\mathbb{P} $. Is an upper bound for this function known ? If yes, is the fact that all non trivial partitions of a prime contain at least  $ 2 $ distinct summands anyhow used in establishing this upper bound ?

Comment: $P_{\Omega}(x,0)$ in here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297785/prime-counting-meissel-lehmer-is-there-a-general-formula/300060

Comment: Thank but I think in that link  $ k $ is a number while I meant  $ \mathbb{A}_{f}(x) $ with  $ f $ a function to denote the number of positive integers  $ n $ below  $ x $ such that the numbers  $ f(n) $ belong to the set  $ \mathbb{A} $ .

Comment: That way,  $ \pi(x) $ is  $ \mathbb{P}_{Id}(x) $ .

Comment: Ok, so $P_{\Omega}(x) = P_2(x,0) + P_3(x,0) + P_5(x,0) +  P_7(x,0)....$ up to max $P_{\lfloor log_{p_{(a+1)}}(x) \rfloor}(x,0)$ ?

Comment: If you prefer, I'm interested in  $ \# \{n\leq x, \Omega(\Omega(n))=1\} $.

Comment: up to $x=15$ this is exactly $x-\pi(x)-1$